# Приходят пустые заявки на сайте

Tags: php, html, ajax, phpmailer

есть вот такая форма обратной связи.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];

    $message = "Заявка.<br>
    Имя: $name,<br>
    Номер телефона: $phone,<br>
    Вопрос: $question <br>
    Заявка отправлена с сайта 
    ";

    $to = "@gmail.com";
    $from = "email.kz";
    $subject = "Заявка с сайта ";
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $to\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo('');
        }
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body{margin:0}#raha_wrapper{position:absolute;width:100vw;height:100vh;display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}#raha_msg{margin:10% auto 0;max-width:70vmin;background-color:transparent;;text-align:center;padding-bottom:1%;border:5px solid #fff}#raha_msg h{font-weight:700;font-size:5vmin}#raha_btn {
  
    /* background-color: #DB0F32; */
    background-color: #0E376F;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    /* max-width: 100%; aidana15031991@gmail.com*/
    margin: 0 auto 10%;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}#raha_btn:hover{cursor:pointer;background-color: #fff;border:1px solid #0E376F; color: #000;}#raha_msg_txt{padding-top:10%;padding-bottom:10%;color:#fff;}
    .raha-box{
      background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    
    }

    .raha-box-title {
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 25px;
      line-height: 23px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #084393;
    }

    .raha-box-text {
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000000;
    }
  
</style>
<div id="raha_wrapper">
  <div class="raha-box">
    <p class="raha-box-title">
      Спасибо за вашу заявку!
    </p>

    <p class="raha-box-text">
      Наш специалист скоро с вами свяжется.
    </p>

    <div id="raha_btn"><span>Вернуться на главную</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('raha_btn').onclick = function (){
  window.history.back();
};

</script>
```

Работает как надо, отправляет заявки, все круто. Только каждую минуту приходят пустые заявки. Поставил required, но все равно приходят пустые заявки. За 3 минуты, 18 пустых заявок

Comment: У вас письмо отправляется при любом заходе на эту страницу. Пришли на неё с формы или просто так. Самый очевидный способ - проверять заполненность полей. типа `if($name or $phone or $question) {mail(...)}`

Comment: @zhurof спасибо, помогло